# Windows 10 Pro Local Account Editor

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

I would like to know if there is a way for me to limit a Standard Windows 10 Pro local user account to a specific set of rules.

Since I have Windows 10 Pro I can use RDS to remote access my PC.

It is also possible to create additional Standard (*Not Administrator of course*) user accounts in case I wish them to exist for different reasons/tasks.

I wish to make user1's experience limited by the following set of rules:

Shortcut in desktop to a specific internal website is allowed.
Nothing else is displayed in desktop.
Start menu only displays LOG OFF only.

Is there a local user account editor that allows for this type of specific editing?

Comment: For this very specific use case, you may be interested in kiosk mode: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app

Comment: Are you using version 1809?  If so you could look at deploying Edge as a single app in kiosk mode.  See : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/microsoft-edge/deploy/microsoft-edge-kiosk-mode-deploy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local group policy editor would effect the computer. If your trying to force certain restrictions on to certain users, I would recommend using the Microsoft Management Console it's included with Windows Pro. These actions can be done locally without a domain connected.
Hopefully this helps you with your problem.

Comment: Ok. I have added Local Users & Groups (Local) Snap-In. Then I noticed that there is not a single useful example to learn from in there. I Would like to customize a user account the way it appears they let you customize a local computer.